# getting different output in unordered manner

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to javascript so please do answer in detail,
I am calling settimeOut first and than calling an anonymous functions
but the out is arranged in opposite manner,
So What i want to know why is it so,is it because of online compiler or any concept
This is the image[image]

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Execute later after 1 second')
}, 1000);

let show = function() {
    console.log('Anonymous function');
};

show();
```

Comment: First thing that came to my mind is this video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to what setTimeout does. setTimeout receives a callback function and a timeout in milliseconds, the execution of the callback function will be delayed by the given amount of the timeout. Meaning that `show()` will be executed first and `console.log("Execute later after 1 second");` after one second.
Long story short setTimeout delays the execution of a given function.
So everything works as it should.